# Swift 3 UIStatusBarStyle not working for separate ViewControllers within UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Something in Swift 3 changed.
I used to be able to change the status bar color from default to light on every `ViewController` even though it was wrapped within a `UINavigationController`.

Right now I have a `UINavigationController` that manages all of my `UIViewController`s and when I'm doing this on each `ViewController` it doesn't work:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

On the other hand, when I'm inserting this code into my subclass of `UINavigationCotroller` it works, but I can't change it dynamically at all, meaning all of my `ViewController`s now have `.lightContent` and I cannot change it.

Is there a solution to this horrifying change?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can change it dynamically to all views in your app by adding         `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` to your AppDelegate.swift file inside your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. You also will need to go to you info.plist file and add the Boolean `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to `NO`.